# How to prevent a part of arbitrary code to be compiled in Python?

Tags: python, optimization, assert

According to [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=assert) `assert` statements aren't included in code if it is compiled with `-O` key. I wondering if it is possible to emulate this behavior with any arbitrary piece of code?

For example, if I have a logger which is called heavily during execution I can benefit from eliminating `if DEBUG: ...` statements with all the code associated to them.

Comment: "I can benefit greatly" -- what led you to believe that?  Do you have timing results demonstrating that the `if DEBUG:` is a bottleneck?

Comment: You are right, it is unlikely to be a bottleneck. I'm writing a library and I want to be sure that client would get the best possible performance.

Comment: If you're looking for something sugary, you could probably do something with decorators.

Comment: Yea, I'm doing something with decorators. But at the end decorators itself aren't free and I assume that `if` statement much cheaper than function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Python is an interpreted language, it can't jump around in its own code.  But you don't need a "special tool" to strip off parts of your code -- use Python for it!

Here is a minimal example.  You'll probably want to put the `strip_debug()` function in your `__init__.py` and let it process a list of modules.  Also, you'd probably want to add some additional check that the user really wants to *modify* the code, not just *run* it.  Probably, using a command line option like `--purge` would be nice.  You can then either make a copy of your library and once run

```
python __init__.py --purge
```

before you publish the library or leave it up to your users to do so.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.2

# BEGIN DEBUG
def _strip_debug():
    """
    Generates an optimized version of its own code stripping off all debugging
    code.

    """
    import os
    import re
    import shutil
    import sys
    import tempfile
    begin_debug = re.compile("^\s*#+\s*BEGIN\s+DEBUG\s*$")
    end_debug = re.compile("^\s*#+\s*END\s+DEBUG\s*$")
    tmp = None
    debug = False
    try:
        tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w", suffix=".py", delete=False)
        with open(sys.argv[0]) as my_code:
            for line in my_code:
                if begin_debug.match(line):
                    debug = True
                    continue
                elif end_debug.match(line):
                    debug = False
                    continue
                else:
                    if not debug:
                        tmp.write(line)
        tmp.close()
        shutil.copy(tmp.name, sys.argv[0])
    finally:
        os.unlink(tmp.name)
# END DEBUG    

def foo(bar, baz):
    """
    Do something weired with bar and baz.

    """
    # BEGIN DEBUG
    if DEBUG:
        print("bar = {}".format(bar))
        print("baz = {}".format(baz))
    # END DEBUG
    return bar + baz


# BEGIN DEBUG
if __name__ == "__main__":
    _strip_debug()
# END DEBUG
```

After executed, this file will only contain the functional code of the `foo()` function.  I have used the special comments

```
# BEGIN DEBUG
```

and

```
# END DEBUG
```

in this example which allows to strip off arbitrary code but if it's just for removing

```
if DEBUG:
    # stuff
```

sections, it would also be pretty easy to detect those without any additional comments.

Comment: Thank you, this is an interesting technique. I was thinking to make user decide if he wants this debug code or not by `-O` flag, like with asserts.

Comment: Addendum:  Would of course be more useful to have in the `setup.py` not in the `__init__.py` file so the user can decide during install whether to pass the option.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just comment out the code you don't want the the # symbol?

Comment: Commenting this code in a lot of places is a menial work, however it is possible to automate it. But I'm looking for something which wouldn't involve a special tool.